# How to work with PDF in PDF/A1-a format using PHP

Tags: pdf, fpdf, tcpdf, mpdf, pdfa

I'd like to generate a PDF file strictly in the PDF/A1-a format (to integrate with a government service).
This service does not support PDF/A1-b or PDF/A1-x format. Only PDF/A1-a.

Previously, I used mPDF (https://mpdf.github.io/) in my work. But this library supports maximum PDF/A1-b.

A search in Google gave no result. But I think that I am not the first one who needed this format. Please tell me if there is something convenient for working with this "rare" format (PDF/A1-a).

Regards, Alexey.

Comment: I think that a "PDF/A1-b" formatted pdf file should be readable by a "PDF/A1-a". You did try to use it as it is and it didn't worked?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, the file in PDF/A1-b did not pass validation.